# Passing remote_user to lua file

Tags: lua, ldap

I am following the [next tuto](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/09/secure-elasticsearch-kibana.html) section LDAP Authentication. The configuration nginx file and the lua script are [here](http://www.e-connecting.com.br/nginx-ldap-auth.conf) and [here](http://www.e-connecting.com.br/authorize_es_ldap.lua). After the commands

```
sbin/nginx -p $PWD -c conf/nginx-ldap-auth.conf
python backend-sample-app.py
python nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py
```

According the log of nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py  I have success with login, i.e. 200 OK auth user admin. But I get a 500 Internal Server Error. In the lua.log I get

```
 /usr/local/openresty/nginx/authorize_es_ldap.lua: in function </usr/local/openresty/nginx/authorize_es_ldap.lua:1> while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8881", referrer: "http://localhost:8881/"
2016/09/29 23:35:27 [error] 23987#0: *10 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /usr/local/openresty/nginx/authorize_es_ldap.lua:50: attempt to concatenate global 'role' (a nil value)
```

I think that the problem is because in the tutorial there is a gap, that is how to pass the remote_user variable to lua script. I am trying to add self.send_header('LDAPUser',ctx['user']) around the line 204, before to end_headers and after to seld.send_response(200).

Could you help me please?

Comment: The lua script you post is different from the one from original tutorial. Please replace `local user = ngx.var.remote_user` to `local role = ngx.var.remote_user`